# Should [discord.py] questions also be tagged [python] and [discord]? Can they be interlinked?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

Many tags are related only to a particular programming language, and it might be of a library that has bindings in many languages. For example, many PyQT questions are tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), though the main library used is [pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt). The question might be related to the programming language (might be a simple `if-else` mistake) or the library (the wrong class/method might've been used), or it might be equally related to both.

I know that there is a tag-linking system, but I'm not sure if [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) is linked. I think both tags should be used, as most library-specific mistakes/bugs can be understood even if in another language, as they're almost the same in any language it has bindings in; related questions can be useful. [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) and [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) are used to make Discord bots, and sometimes, the problem's the same, but only the programming language is different (Python/JavaScript/...), so one could understand how to solve the problem and code accordingly in the language one uses.

But as a question can have only 5 tags, adding [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) might sometimes not be possible, as there might be other, more important tags which the question is actually about. For example, a question might be about a problem with a [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) music bot, which might use [youtube-dl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-dl), and another problem might be with [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg).

Can [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) questions automatically be also tagged [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)? And if there's space for the two, should questions also be tagged [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (manually)?

Comment: There is no tag-linking system.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, what do you mean? It might not be called so, but similar tags are *merged with each other* (?) (I guess I took this in the wrong sense). Would a tag-linking system be approved, or are the developers still working on fixing some other important features? But tagging is to categorize relevant content, right? I thought there's a system/process for this and that there were many ways to do it. Would I get [discord.py] questions in a `[python]` (newest) Stack Overflow search even if they aren't tagged [python] as of now? Or are they already *linked*?

Comment: *Identical* tags can be merged together, which results in renaming one existing tag to match another existing tag. That doesn't work in this case, as it effectively removes the old tag from the system. You would *not* get questions tagged [discord.py] now when searching for [python] unless they were also tagged [python] (as they should be, if they are, in fact, about Python). It has always been this way. Tag linking as you're suggesting has been suggested for over a decade now, but it has never been implemented, and there's no indication that anyone has ever worked on it.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, then how does Stack Overflow search present relevant questions on the site? Oh, then I guess I randomly imagined something. If it's yet to be implemented, would a feature request make the process faster? I thought tags with `.py`, `.js`, etc., are automatically linked with the respective programming languages. Why not implement a simple system, at least? The same approval/rejection queue system so that not all tags which *have* 'py' are linked so (`pyqt`, for example). The tags would be used only* to include [discord.py] questions in [discord] and [python] searches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an official standard, but what seems to be the common practice is:

- If a question is about an implementation (i.e., not a theoretical computer-science question about algorithms, or a language-agnostic question [about logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/)), tag the appropriate language even if other tags might appear to be redundant with it.
- (Not applicable here) If the question is about a language feature, tag the language-specific version of the feature if possible, and otherwise a more general tag about a language feature.
- If the question is about a task that requires an API (i.e., use of the API is essential to reproduce the problem for a what-is-wrong question, or is what is expected to be used for a how-to question), tag the language-specific version of the API almost always
- For language-agnostic APIs, additionally use the agnostic tag *if* the question is about *the API itself* - i.e., how it's designed, the underlying concepts/paradigms etc.

Example: [Client.__init__() "missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'", or "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420) is properly tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py). It would merit [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) if, rather than being about resolving the error described, it were a more theoretical question about what the Discord API means by "intents", what the default intents signify, what can be customized with them etc.

Comment: Yes, it'd be immensely self-handicapping to exclude `python`, as there's many `python` watchers willing to answer various API questions that they aren't watching. The exceptions described in this answer also make sense. I think they're good guidelines for all languages.

Comment: But why should the example not be tagged [discord]? I mean, that is a very common and basic error, so it would have at least 100 questions and answers about it for discord.js. But what about rarer questions like ones about unused properties that both discord.py and discord.js have, but many discord.py questions about that property have been asked? Someone using discord.js might find that post helpful, as it might be a basic property, and it might have to be used in a similar way in discord.js, so adding the [discord] tag to those questions might show potentially helpful questions.

Comment: And I guess discord.py is better documented than discord.js (I remember seeing discord.js docs, but I'm not too sure), and as discord.py is usually updated on par with discord.js, any functionality discord.py provides would be there in discord.js, so it shouldn't be an issue, and simple properties and methods can directly be tried and tested, even if much info about how to use them is not available.

Answer (score 2):

As Py is shorthand for Python, and question relates to Discord, I think both tags (Python and Discord) are valid.